# Verify Credentials for Nurse Practitioner

Tags: practice-of-medicine, health-education, medical-training, qualifiy-certify, nurse-practitioner

There is a Nurse Practitioner near our home who can do most routine things Doctors can do, i.e. blood test, flu shot, etc, etc

What websites can help verify credentials, education, complaints, etc of a Nurse Practitioner?

For instance, https://www.certificationmatters.org verifies if Doctor is board certified, and many states, such as New York, has website such as http://nydoctorprofile.com/ that will give details such as education, types of insurance accepted, malpractice lawsuits, etc.

By the way I am in New York State

Thanks for your guidance

Comment: What state do you live in? Your state health department quite likely has a web site where you can lookup health providers but you don't say what state you're in.

Comment: @CareyGregory I am in New York State

Comment: http://www.op.nysed.gov/opsearches.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each state should have their own licensing board, that may or may not have a search function to verify a licensure.

As an experiment, I went to the [Texas website](https://www.bon.texas.gov/forms/apninq.asp) and entered the name of a nurse practitioner that I gathered off of the internet, and it came back with a verification of their initial licensure, how long it was good for, and the recognized level of accreditation.

Your own state should have a way to verify all licensed medical practitioners in the state.